# Kafka Server and Kafka Cluster

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I'm currently working with Kafka via Springboot. I have been only using Kafka for sending email, so application doesn't have to wait till we send an email. For this use case I had a single Kafka server which was hosted in the AWS server. My question is: if this single Kafka server is down, will Kafka be working or will my data be lost? I know Kafka is fault tolerant, but it works if we have two or more Kafka servers. In my case I have only one Kafka server ... How Kafka will handle the data here?

One way we could handle this is by monitoring the Kafka AWS. Then we can be able to investigate further and make the Kafka server available.

Is there any other ways to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka is not fault tolerant when there is only one broker. If that broker is down, your producer will drop the events and return an error

You need at least 2 brokers in a cluster **and** set your topic replication factor to at least 2.